# Unfortunately, APP has stopped error. Are there any view limitations for an activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to develop an app for Android with Android studio.
I have a login page and trying to open an another activity named main with button from login page. I have lots of rows in two table layout. You can find codes there.
When i clicked imagebutton in login, sometimes i get Unfortunately, APP has stopped error. Sometimes dont get **with same codes.**

Are there any limitations for number of widgets for an activity page?
I am getting this error on emulator.
Here are the codes.
Thank for your replies.

**login.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    Button mainBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_enter);
    mainBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
```

**content_main**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.dasyapi.erp.dait.main"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="@drawable/gravis">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/ust_logo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:id="@+id/ly_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/iv_logo">


        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tl_content">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_ajanda"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_ajanda"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/ajanda"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_kasa"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_kasa"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/kasa"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_siparis"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_siparis"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/siparis"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_puantaj"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_puantaj"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/puantaj"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_gelirler"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_gelirler"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/gelirler"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_giderler"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_giderler"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/giderler"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_stoklar"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_stoklar"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/stoklar"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_kritik"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_kritik"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/kritik"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ly_sikayet"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="146dp"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ibt_sikayet"
                        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:keepScreenOn="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/sikayet"
                        android:clickable="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ly_tutanak"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="146dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ibt_tutanak"
                    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:keepScreenOn="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/tutanak"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ly_is_kazasi"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="146dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ibt_is_kazasi"
                    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:keepScreenOn="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/is_kazasi"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ly_kamera"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="@color/dBlueDark"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="146dp"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ibt_kamera"
                    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:keepScreenOn="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/kamera"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:id="@+id/fl_bottom">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/tl_bottom">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:id="@+id/tr_bottom">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/ll_personel">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ibt_personel"
                    android:background="@color/dOrange"
                    android:src="@drawable/personel"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/ll_taseron">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ibt_taseron"
                    android:background="@color/dOrange"
                    android:src="@drawable/taseron"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/ll_musteri">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ibt_musteri"
                    android:background="@color/dOrange"
                    android:src="@drawable/musteri"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/ll_threedots">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ibt_threedots"
                    android:background="@color/dOrange"
                    android:src="@drawable/diger"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the error message you received in your logs. "Unfortunately app has stopped" is not the error. That's just telling you the app crashed. So please post the full text of the error so we can see what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **onClick** method outside **onCreate** like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
 public void Click(View v) {
    if (s.getId() == R.id.bt_enter) {
        Intent y = new Intent(login.this, main.class);
        startActivity(y);

    }
}
```

Here Click is the onClick id of your Button which you can define in your xml

```
android:onClick="Click"
```